# Touch location inside an object

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, location, uitouch

I when I try using the following line of code:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let tap = touch as UITouch
        let location = tap.locationInView(self.view)
        print(location( 
}
```

I can not get the location of the touch inside a picker view. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

this is how i do it..First you need to assign your object a name and then in touchesBegan you need to specify that the location of the touch is the same with the object

```
 let location = (touch as! UITouch).locationInNode(self)
            if let name = self.nodeAtPoint(location).name {
                if name == "objectName" {
// do your code here
}
```